# Add custom click event on the remove mini cart button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to add a custom click event to the remove button in the mini cart

```
function ajax_call(){
$.ajax({
      url: ajax_url,
      type: 'post',
      data: {action : 'remove_from_cart','cart_item_key' : 10},
      beforeSend: function(res){
        console.log('loading');
      },
      success: function(res){
        $('.widget_shopping_cart_content ').replaceWith(res); // once this worked, the click function below became not working
}
});
}

$('.remove_from_cart_button').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    ajax_call();
});
```

Some of the code I've tried doesn't work

```
$('.widget_shopping_cart_content .remove_from_cart_button').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.widget_shopping_cart_content .remove_from_cart_button', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: it seems because .widget_shopping_cart_content got from ajax call

Comment: and just for information, .remove_from_cart_button is the class for the link <a class="remove_from_cart_button" href="...

Comment: Without knowing that `res` HTML looks like - hard to tell, but  [this solution should work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14533243/383904) using delegation. Just make sure to use the right selectors.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure your `$(document.body)` one should work at least. Since you mentioned it's loaded dynamically from ajax. As long as you register an event relative to an element that wasn't reloaded, it should work (in your case the document.body should be fine). I'm assuming you had some functions running after the `e.preventDefault()`? Do those functions have any errors? I don't know your html structure, but you could also confirm you're not accidentally overwriting a parent element when you finish the ajax call (this would break the ".widget_shopping_cart_content .remove_from_cart_button" node tree). I'd need a bit more info like the html structure, what the button functions are doing and maybe the structure of the js file itself to help more, but hopefully this helps.

**EDIT:**
The only other thing I can think of, sometimes you can need to wrap your handlers in this function to make sure the document is ready.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    ...
});
```

Comment: yes, I called another function after e.preventDefault(). click() function actually works but only once, when .widget_shopping_cart_content is updated by ajax or page is refreshed it becomes not working

Answer (score 0):

You're **replacing (using `.replaceWith()`)** `.widget_shopping_cart_content` with some other HTML, so you cannot use any more that `.widget_shopping_cart_content` selector since it's removed from the DOM. Instead use only the newly generated `.remove_from_cart_button`

```js
$(document).on('click', '.remove_from_cart_button', function(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  console.log($(this)); // Your $Button
});
```

which should work since it uses [Event delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14533243/383904)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for the answers, I just found a function that is wc_fragments_refreshed which is the answer to my question this time. my mistake, I should have made the question more specific, namely ***adding a function when an item on the mini cart is removed***.

```
$(document.body).on('wc_fragments_refreshed', function(){
  $('.remove_from_cart_button').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```